# Remove ;# from exported csv sharepoint list

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

Might be a simple question but can't seem to find the answer im looking for else where.

Ive exported a SharePoint list as a csv that contains a couple of People and Group picker fields, when export it adds the unique id infront of the name of the person/group ie:

123;#Bob Smith

What i want to achieve is that it displays Bob Smith as the value so remove ;# and everything before that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show us code, and the error that you are receiving?

Comment: Ive originally tried removing that part of the string but i couldnt do this dynmically and only remove the ;# part: '(gc "C:\Temp\Assets.CSV") | #% {$_ -replace ';#', ""}  | out-file $AttachmentPath -Fo -En ascii'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, thank you for showing your code (next time it's better if you edit the question rather than putting it into a comment).

This will load the CSV file, and for each record it will replace the undesirable text with nothing, and output the modified record, and will output to an updated file.

```
import-csv C:\temp\Assets.csv|%{
    $_.UserName = $_.UserName -replace ".*;#"
    $_
}|export-csv c:\temp\assets2.csv -notype
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this, where NameOfField is the name of the field or property you want to clean up.

```
$results = Import-CSV pathtofile.csv | Select-Object *,@{n='NameOfField';e={$_.NameOfField -replace '.*;#'}} -excludeproperty NameOfField
$results | Export-CSV pathtonewfile.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: This is going to throw errors for each record stating that it can not add a property 'NameOfField' because it already exists (as it is included in `*` previously)

Comment: Not if you use -ExcludeProperty as I did above.This is handy for altering a single property within the pipeline.